# CDO.Message with style tag or external CSS?

Tags: css, vbscript, outlook, cdo.message

Is it possible to use CSS via a style section or even an external CSS file from a VBScript using CDO.Message to send email?

Here is what I've tried:

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
...
objMessage.HtmlBody= "<style type='text/css'>headr {font-weight: bold;}</style>" & _
    "<table><tr class='headr'><td>test1</td><td>test2</td></tr>" &_
    ...

...
objMessage.Send
```

Which doesn't work.  However, doing it inline does:

```
objMessage.HtmlBody= "<table><tr style='font-weight:bold;'><td>test1</td><td>test2</td></tr>" &_
```

All messages will be delivered to Outlook.

Comment: This probably has more to do with the mail client's ability to interpret `style` elements. CDO is just a delivery mechanism.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a simple typo not related to the actual technologies referenced in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether CDO or the Outlook object model is responsible for delivering emails. The viewer plays the key role there.

As you may probably know Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup. The following articles describe supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the . in my class definition.

It works fine.

:|